# MongoDB - get documents with max attribute per group in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My data looks like this:

```
session, age, firstName, lastName
1, 28, John, Doe
1, 21, Donna, Keren
2, 32, Jenna, Haze
2, 52, Tommy, Lee
..
..
```

I'd like to get all the rows which are the largest (by age) per session. So So for the above input my output would look like:

```
sessionid, age, firstName, lastName
1, 28, John, Doe
2, 52, Tommy, Lee
```

because John has the largest age in the session = 1 group and Tommy has the largest age on the session=2 group.

I need to export the result to a file (csv) and it may contain lots of records.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You could try the below aggregation query which uses max attribute: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   $group: {
       "_id": "$session",           
       "age": { $max: "$age" }
     },
   { $out : "max_age" }
])
```

The results should be outputted to the new collection max_age and then you could dump it into a csv.

Note: it will give only the session and max age and will not return other fields.

Comment: You didn't read the question. `$max` does not cut it for "whole" records.

Comment: @NeilLunn I do not understand what you are trying to say but I hope you have read the note in my answer.

Comment: @orcaman Cannot even remotely work to what you asked. `$max` disseminates a singular item from a single field. You asked for a whole "row" of data to be returned. This is not your answer and you a doing a major disservice to to future people by accepting something that does not answer your question.

Comment: The question and accepted answer are totally unrelated.

Comment: How many negative votes until you remove this confusing answer from the public sphere?

Comment: @AugieGardner I am sorry to hear that this is confusing and I would be happy to remove it but SO does not allow to remove accepted answer :( .

Comment: @LalitAgarwal ah I see.  Time to start commenting on the OPs answers so he does his civic duty then

Answer (score 19):

MongoDB aggregation offers the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator, but in your case you want the "whole" record as it is. So the appropriate thing to do here is [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and then use the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator within a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "session": 1, "age": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$session",
        "age": { "$first": "$age" },
        "firstName": { "$first" "$firstName" },
        "lastName": { "$first": "$lastName" }
    }}
])
```

So the "sorting" gets the order right, and the "grouping" picks the first occurrence within the "grouping" key where those fields exist.

Mostly `$first` here because the `$sort` is done in reverse order. You can also use [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) when in an ascending order as well.

Comment: Cheers. I've tried to use this, but for some reason I am only getting one document as a result. see my question (I edited it to add some code).

Comment: @orcaman You change terms in your question. Is the field i you document called "session" or is it "sessionid". Look at the concepts of the code examples rather than rely on "cut and paste"

Comment: Hi Neil, I did not cut & paste at all - my actual structure is quite different (session or sessionid typo is not relevant to the error as far as I can gather). Please review my question above (I edited it to explain).