# Get elements with biggest attribute using find only

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, nosql

**EDIT**: Ok, got it. It cannot be done with a find. I workarounded this in another way, but its *pretty unrelated* with this question: i added a boolean field "last_inserted" and used meteor hooks to make sure that only the last inserted have that field. Thank you all anyway.

I'm in a **Meteor** project and have a collection like this:

```
group_id, date, attribute1, attributeN
1, 2015-11-26 09:40:23.000Z, "foo", "bar"
1, 2015-11-23 14:23:53.000Z, "foo", "bar"
2, 2015-11-23 14:24:01.000Z, "foo", "bar"
2, 2015-11-23 14:25:44.000Z, "foo", "bar"
```

i have to filter this and get, for each group_id, the element with the biggest date, having a result like this:

```
group_id, date, attribute1, attributeN
1, 2015-11-26 09:40:23.000Z, "foo", "bar"
2, 2015-11-23 14:25:44.000Z, "foo", "bar"
```

I read in some related question that it can be done with the `aggregate` operator:
[MongoDB - get documents with max attribute per group in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892928/mongodb-get-documents-with-max-attribute-per-group-in-a-collection)

but Meteor *still doesn't implement it*, and i have to do it with a `find`.

I'm no MongoDB expert and i'm reading the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) from a lot, but i'm starting to fear that i can't do this without getting **all** the elements and manually filtering those in javascript (i really don't like this kind of solution)

I read there are some meteor packages that adds the aggregate command (like [this](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate)), but i don't know how much they are reliable since this is a project that needs to be rock-solid

How can i do that?

Comment: like i wrote in the question: "i have to filter this and get, for each group_id, the element with the biggest date". So, for all the items with the same group_id i have to get only the one with the biggest date

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad. I fix the question right now :)

Comment: You understand the basics of what `.find()` is meant to do don't you? And you understand that what you are asking for is the document with the largest field value from a "grouping" boundary? Right? ( I mean, you even called it group_id ). It should be pretty clear that `.find()` cannot do this and `.aggregate()` ( and specifically pipeline stages that "group" ) is the tool for this. Of course meteor can use `.aggregate()`, it's not independant software, it uses the core node driver. You only can't `.aggregate()` in a browser. Which is a good thing with a database.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'm still not a big friend of "aggregate" (loses reactivity) and i preferred workaround this problem in another way

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal in plain Javascript with a temporary object for the references to the result array.

```js
var data = [{ group_id: 1, date: '2015-11-26 09:40:23.000Z', attribute1: 'foo', attributeN: 'bar' }, { group_id: 1, date: '2015-11-23 14:23:53.000Z', attribute1: 'foo', attributeN: 'bar' }, { group_id: 2, date: '2015-11-23 14:24:01.000Z', attribute1: 'foo', attributeN: 'bar' }, { group_id: 2, date: '2015-11-23 14:25:44.000Z', attribute1: 'foo', attributeN: 'bar' }],
    result = function (data) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!(a.group_id in o)) {
                o[a.group_id] = r.push(a) - 1;
                return;
            }
            if (a.date > r[o[a.group_id]].date) {
                r[o[a.group_id]] = a;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```