# MongoDB - find ids of documents with the highest value in a group

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, aggregation-framework

Assume the following collection:

```
_id:1, humanId:A, value:10
_id:2, humanId:A, value:20
_id:3, humanId:B, value:33
```

**Question:**

What is the easiest way to find the ids of the documents that have the highest `value` when grouped by `humanId`, i.e. to get the output `[2, 3]`.

**Bonus question:**

Can this be done using Doctrine ODM query builder?

Comment: The logic is explained in ["MongoDB - get documents with max attribute per group in a collection"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892928/mongodb-get-documents-with-max-attribute-per-group-in-a-collection) ( the correct answer and not the accepted one :-< ) You need the aggregation framework and `$sort` to do that. Should be samples of using the aggregation framework with doctrine around here somewhere.

Comment: Awesome, @NeilLunn, thank you! Got it moving thanks to the link to your unaccepted answer. Feel free to copy the logic into an answer here, I'll be happy to accept to do you justice :-).