# Does MongoDB keep sort order for input data during grouping?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let you have next data:

```
{"_id":"1", name="A", age=10}
{"_id":"2", name="B", age=5}
{"_id":"3", name="A", age=1}
```

And you perform next aggregation query:

```
{ "$sort" : { "age" : 1}}
{
   $group:
     {
       _id: "$name",
       document: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
     }
 }
```

Does it mean that I'll get documents with the smallest age in each group if I take always first element from each group?

In other words **does MongoDB guarante that during grouping each group remains sorted by "age" field**?

P.S. Interested only such case and not how this task can be resolved by using $min operator in $group stage or something like that

Comment: *"Does it mean that I'll get documents with the smallest age in each group"*. Yes it does. Does it mean that "A" comes out before "B" in the results? No it does not because you did not ask it to. But applying `$sort` before a `$first` or `$last` is actually the intended usage. `$min` and `$max` work differently by of course just extracting the single value.

Comment: @NeilLunn You got my point, thanks, also I read this doc [mongo $first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25893214/6066505) but **there is a slight difference**, in `$sort` stage you firstly sort by field (e.g. `"session": 1`) you are going to group later, unlike my example above. **Does it make difference?**

Comment: It makes no difference. `$sort` does exactly what it implies it does, as do using `$first` or `$last`. The `$sort` "sorts" as the the accumulators act on the grouping `_id`. Whether or not the sort key and the grouping `_id` are the same thing does not matter to the "order of collection". Since that was determined by the `$sort`.