# Get max of virtual field of each type of record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB with mongoose. I have a collection of orders, each order has currenc (usd, eur, ils and so on) and percent.

My node application reads a value from another service, and my Order collection has virtual field called price that is calculated from that value and the percent of the order document.

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { priceValue } from '../services/price-value';

const orderSchema = new Schema({
    currency: {
        type: 'String',
        required: true
    },
    percent: {
        type: 'Number',
        required: true
    }
}, {
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
});

orderSchema.virtual('price').get(function() {
    return priceValue * this.percent;
});

export default mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

I need to find the max prices for each currency. Something like, for each CURRENCY call:

```
db.orders.find({ currency: CURRENCY }).sort({percent: -1}).limit(1);
```

collect the results in the node application and calculate the virtual price field.
But this feels incorrect. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Is `priceValue` meant to be a `function`? Or is it just a constant value? If it's a function it's missing the `()`, and you would need to iterate a "cursor" ( albeit an aggregation cursor ) result to apply. But if it's a "constant", then you can simply feed the value to the necessary aggregation pipeline and calculate.

Comment: @NeilLunn priceValue is a value. How can I feed the value to the necessary aggregation pipeline? I am trying to avoid repeating the logic behind the virtual field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "virtual fields" you would delegate this to the aggregation framework, which is a lot better then querying for each possible "currency" value.

Where `priceValue` is a simple "constant" value, then you just supply it as such to the pipeline expression:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "currency": 1, "percent": -1 } }, 
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$currency",
    "percent": { 
      "$first": { 
        "$multiply": [ 
          { "$divide": [ "$percent", 100 ] },
          priceValue
        ] 
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

So you [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to keep things in order of "currency" and descending on each "percent" within that "currency". Then you [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on each distinct "currency", taking the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) from each grouping boundary.

Then all you need do is apply [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) to the returned value by the `priceValue` constant, from the "percent" value after [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) by `100`, since you need the divisor for the whole value actually stored.

You should also be aware that returned documents from aggregation pipelines do not have the same schema attached methods as from the model used. The basic reason is you typically "change the shape" of the documents returned, and therefore the "schema" no longer applies.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25893214/2308005), you need aggregation, it's a single call to database

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "currency": 1, "percent": -1 } }, // or "percent": 1
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$currency",
        "percent": { "$first": "$percent" }
    }}
])
```

Result should looks something like, its sorted by max percent and uniquely grouped by currency

```
[{_id: 'usd', percent: 12}, {_id: 'eur', percent: 34}]
```

Then you can use your

```
import { priceValue } from '../services/price-value';
```

To get price

Comment: One issue with this kind of solution, instead of using the virtual filed implementation, I have to duplicate the logic and calculate it again on this query result.