# Mongo DB query only get one document with external Id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say I have a collection with these documents: 
[image]

The bottom two documents have the same firebaseUserId. How do I form a query that only gets one of the two documents with the same firebaseUserId? I would like the document it chooses to be of my choosing, for example, whichever one has the highest value for the field 'testinnn'.

I would be performing the query with other filters as well, like where testinnn is greater than a number for example. I just need to make it decide which document to choose if it runs into two documents with the same firebaseUserId

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) and limit for this [limit()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) like so:

```
db.collection.find({ firebaseUserId: "KnQEqsekY9XV3ayOx082xw8VQX2", "testinnn": { $gt: 1 }  /*add other filters as required*/ })
             .sort({ "testinnn": -1 /*sort by 'testinnn' descending */ })
             .limit(1)
```

Comment: no, because you are assuming I know what the firebaseUserId is, when in fact I won't know what it is

Comment: I see, that bit wasn't obvious to me from the question. Your answer using the aggregation framework (`$group`) is the right way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25893214/8594124

First I sort:

```
{
  testinnn: -1
}
```

Then I get the first one:

```
{
  _id: "$firebaseUserId",
  owner_id: { 
   $first: "$owner_id"
  },
  testinnn: {
    $first: "$testinnn"
  }
}
```