# MongoDB: group, then retrieve entry with max value for each group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In the collection below, I'd like to group by `author`, and then, for each `author`, show the `name` of the entry with the highest `price`.

```
[
  { "name": "Design", "price": 499, "author": "ted" },
  { "name": "Launch", "price": 999, "author": "ted" },
  { "name": "Test",  "price": 1200, "author": "bob" },
  { "name": "Scale",  "price": 1499, "author": "bob" }
]
```

So, here my query should return `Launch` and `Scale`.

I've tried aggregating as follows, but I'm not sure what to do afterwards, short of pulling all entries onto the client and then processing all the groups to find the entry with the max price (which sounds very inefficient).

```
[
  {
    "$group": {
       "_id": "$author",
       "entry": {
         "$push": {
           "price": "$price",
           "name": "$name"
         }
       }
    }
  }
]
```

What's an efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the answer from [MongoDB - get documents with max attribute per group in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892928/mongodb-get-documents-with-max-attribute-per-group-in-a-collection)

please have a try

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": {  "price": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$author",
        "price": { "$first": "$price" },
        "name": { "$first" "$name" }
    }}
])
```